# Low gradient values while training convolutional neural network

Tags: conv-neural-network

I am training a neural network with 3 convolutional layers and 1 fully connected layer which further connected to a regression layer. My training data set if TID: for image quality estimation task. I am pre-processing images by doing local contrast normalization on a small 6 * 6 window, which results in pixel values ranging from -4 to +4 approximately. I am using RELU activation function in all the layers.

The problem is that the gradient values for different layers produced by my network are very small, somewhere around 2e<sup>-6</sup> to 2e<sup>-7</sup>, which I guess are not ideal for good convergence as it is not producing expected results. I have already tried altering initialization of network weights and biases, changing learning rates, employing L1 and L2 regularization, etc., but nothing seems to be help elevate this problem.

So my first question is that is it actually a problem? or is a common thing to have such small gradient values in convolutional network? If it is a problem then what could an appropriate solution for it?

Comment: Those gradients do seem pretty small... Is it like that on every layer? Have you tried scaling your inputs to be in -1 to 1 range? Can you give an estimate on how many different parameters are being learned? (size of filters, number of filters, number of neurons in FC layer)

Comment: Hi Frobot, thanks for your reply. I am using scaled inputs: unit variance and 0 mean. It think scaling between -1 and 1 should not be really important because I am using RELU activation function. Total there are around 4K parameters: 3 convolutional layers (3*11*11*100; 100*5*5*100; 100*3*3*100), 1 fully connected layer (400*100) and 1 regression layer (100 * 1). Could you also give me an estimate of what is a normal scale of good gradient?